# Ошибка .jpg после загрузке на WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sass

```css
.slide:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(52, 47, 63, 0.6)), to(rgba(52, 47, 63, 0.7))), url(.jpg);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(52, 47, 63, 0.6) 0%, rgba(52, 47, 63, 0.7) 100%), url(.jpg);
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: url('../img/cursor-pull.svg'), pointer;
}
```

Есть проект, который делал не я, но я его дорабатываю. И так получилось, что прошлый человек использовал SASS, а я с ним никогда не работал. Сразу было все хорошо, но когда закинул на WordPress, в консоли появилась ошибка .jpg где-то в css файлах. Я нашел это, но не знаю что с этим сейчас делать, как это вообще работает и можно ли вообще удалить? И если вообще удалить, то что будет? Или как можно исправить эту ошибку? Возможно и sass тут не при чем, но я никогда не сталкивался вот с таким написанием
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: замените просто на тот путь к изображению, который вам нужен

Comment: Во первых код нужно показывать кодом, а не картинкой, а во вторых адреса должны быть абсолютные.

Comment: тут можете почитать как это работает https://caffeinecreations.ca/blog/sass-variable-for-image-path/

Comment: Извините, вставил кодом. А если картинок несколько под одним классом, можно ли как-то сделать или нужно каждой класс давать?